# Returning a table from an Oracle function

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, oracle11g

I've looked at many solutions here to try to solve this and they have gotten pretty far but now I'm in the weeds on some errors that I can#t seem to get past.

I am on Oracle 11g. I need a function to return a record set (table). Here is the code I'm using:

```
CREATE TYPE T_TABLE IS OBJECT
(
    Field1 int
    , Field2 int
);

CREATE TYPE T_TABLE_COLL IS TABLE OF T_TABLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_MyFunction
RETURN T_TABLE_COLL 
IS
BEGIN
  FOR I IN (SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM Table1) LOOP
    IF I.Field1 = 1 THEN
        BEGIN           
            INSERT INTO T_TABLE     
            SELECT Field1, Field2
            FROM Table2
            WHERE Field2 = I.Field2;
        END;
    ELSIF I.Field1 = 2 THEN
        BEGIN           
            INSERT INTO T_TABLE     
            SELECT Field1, Field2
            FROM Table2
            WHERE Field2 = I.Field2;
        END;  
  END IF;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN T_SMRYACCT_TABLE_COLL;
END;
```

The errors I receive from this are:

1. Statement Ignored on the FUNCTION FN_MyFunction line and PL/SQL: ORA-04044: procedure, function, package, or type is not allowed here on each line INSERT INTO T_TABLE_COLL line
2. PLS-00330: invalid use of type name or subtype name on the RETURN line

What am I doing wrong with the table types?

Comment: If you are doing insert/update or delete use a stored procedure rather than a function.

Comment: I need to join the results to additional tables, I dont believe I could use an SP in a join clause.

Answer (score 5):

`T_TABLE_COLL` is a collection. You cannot use **insert** on collections.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_MyFunction
RETURN T_TABLE_COLL
IS
  l_res_coll T_TABLE_COLL;
  l_index number;
BEGIN
  l_res_coll := T_TABLE_COLL();
  FOR I IN (SELECT col1, col2 FROM Table1)
  LOOP
    IF I.col1 = 1 THEN
      l_res_coll.extend;
      l_index := l_res_coll.count;  
      l_res_coll(l_index):= T_TABLE(i.col1, i.col2);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  return l_res_coll;
END;
```

Function in action

```
select *
  from table(FN_MyFunction())
```

To get more information about what collections are and how to use them read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#CIHIEBJC)

Comment: Kudos for answering! One quick point you've removed the `elsif`, which was doing nothing. I think this was a coding error on the OPs part rather than anything else...

Comment: Thanks for the response. I missed that this was a collection. One follow up question though, do you see any more straight forward ways of returning a table from a function? Im actually converting TSQL code that was using a table-value function which is not converted easily to PLSQL.

Comment: corrected the ELSIF to be relevant, it was a conversation error. the actual SQL has about 6 ELSIF's, didnt think to was unnecessary to post them all.

Comment: Take a look at this http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10765/pipe_paral_tbl.htm#i1007118.