# Convert oracle query to stored procedure for SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS)

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, reporting-services, oracle11g

How can I convert this query to a stored procedure that returns also the same(fields) table:

```
SELECT   R.REGION_NAME,
           TP.TERRITORY_NAME,
           LSC.LOOKUP_NAME,
           CAST (WM_CONCAT (CM.CUST_NAME) AS VARCHAR2 (500)) AS CUST_NAMES,
           TP.VIEWER_PROFILE,
           TP.CASTING_PREFERENCE,
           TP.PROG_TYPE_PREFERENCE,
           STN_LIST.STN_NAMES,
           STN_LIST.LIC_RIGHTS
    FROM               TERRITORY_PROFILE_MSTR TP
                    INNER JOIN
                       REGION_MSTR R
                    ON TP.REGION_ID = R.REGION_ID
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    LOOKUP_SUB_CATEGORY LSC
                 ON TP.BROADCAST_STD_CD = LSC.LOOKUP_SUB_CAT_ID
              LEFT OUTER JOIN
                 CUST_MSTR CM
              ON CM.TERRITORY_ID = TP.TERRITORY_ID
           LEFT OUTER JOIN
              (SELECT   CAST (WM_CONCAT (SLR.CUST_STN_NAME) AS VARCHAR2 (500))
                             AS STN_NAMES,
                          CAST (WM_CONCAT (LRM.LIC_RIGHTS_ID) AS VARCHAR2 (500))
                             AS LIC_RIGHTS,
                          SLR.CUST_COMPETITOR_ID AS CUST_ID
                   FROM   STN_LIC_RIGHTS SLR, LIC_RIGHTS_MSTR LRM
                  WHERE   SLR.STN_LIC_ID = LRM.LIC_RIGHTS_ID
               GROUP BY   SLR.CUST_COMPETITOR_ID) STN_LIST
           ON STN_LIST.CUST_ID = CM.CUST_ID
   WHERE   TP.TERRITORY_ID <> 0
GROUP BY   TP.TERRITORY_NAME,
           R.REGION_NAME,
           LSC.LOOKUP_NAME,
           STN_LIST.STN_NAMES,
           STN_LIST.LIC_RIGHTS,
           TP.VIEWER_PROFILE,
           TP.CASTING_PREFERENCE,
           TP.PROG_TYPE_PREFERENCE
ORDER BY   R.REGION_NAME, TP.TERRITORY_NAME
```

I think I don't need to specify the table structure. Please take note that the query is fully functional and the values are correctly return the way I expect it to return.

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

**The stored procedure must be compatible and executable in ASP.NET(C#) through SQL Server Reporting Services or SSRS.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody mentioned any alternative to my question like the use of Oracle `VIEWS`.

Instead of creating a stored procedure for my SSRS reports, I can use `VIEWS` though they don't have any parameters, it answers my question.

For future reference here's the code:

```
CREATE VIEW RV_TERRITORY_PROFILE
AS
SELECT   R.REGION_NAME,
           TP.TERRITORY_NAME,
           LSC.LOOKUP_NAME,
           CAST (WM_CONCAT (CM.CUST_NAME) AS VARCHAR2 (500)) AS CUST_NAMES,
           TP.VIEWER_PROFILE,
           TP.CASTING_PREFERENCE,
           TP.PROG_TYPE_PREFERENCE,
           STN_LIST.STN_NAMES,
           STN_LIST.LIC_RIGHTS
    FROM               TERRITORY_PROFILE_MSTR TP
                    INNER JOIN
                       REGION_MSTR R
                    ON TP.REGION_ID = R.REGION_ID
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    LOOKUP_SUB_CATEGORY LSC
                 ON TP.BROADCAST_STD_CD = LSC.LOOKUP_SUB_CAT_ID
              LEFT OUTER JOIN
                 CUST_MSTR CM
              ON CM.TERRITORY_ID = TP.TERRITORY_ID
           LEFT OUTER JOIN
              (SELECT   CAST (WM_CONCAT (SLR.CUST_STN_NAME) AS VARCHAR2 (500))
                             AS STN_NAMES,
                          CAST (WM_CONCAT (LRM.LIC_RIGHTS_ID) AS VARCHAR2 (500))
                             AS LIC_RIGHTS,
                          SLR.CUST_COMPETITOR_ID AS CUST_ID
                   FROM   STN_LIC_RIGHTS SLR, LIC_RIGHTS_MSTR LRM
                  WHERE   SLR.STN_LIC_ID = LRM.LIC_RIGHTS_ID
               GROUP BY   SLR.CUST_COMPETITOR_ID) STN_LIST
           ON STN_LIST.CUST_ID = CM.CUST_ID
   WHERE   TP.TERRITORY_ID <> 0
GROUP BY   TP.TERRITORY_NAME,
           R.REGION_NAME,
           LSC.LOOKUP_NAME,
           STN_LIST.STN_NAMES,
           STN_LIST.LIC_RIGHTS,
           TP.VIEWER_PROFILE,
           TP.CASTING_PREFERENCE,
           TP.PROG_TYPE_PREFERENCE
ORDER BY   R.REGION_NAME, TP.TERRITORY_NAME
```

then you can run it like

```
SELECT * FROM RV_TERRITORY_PROFILE
```

Comment: But how will you send parameters to the view ? actually you did get that answer - it's in the ["parameterized view" link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024696/creating-parameterized-views-in-oracle11g)

Comment: Aha. I see.. Sorry. I'm focused on my own research. But if the answer is more specific and not just links, I can accept it.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways to do what you're asking:

1. By using a function / procedure which returns a sys_refcursor as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170548/get-resultset-from-oracle-stored-procedure)
2. By using a "parameterized view" as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024696/creating-parameterized-views-in-oracle11g)
3. By using a table functions as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338573/returning-a-table-from-an-oracle-function)

and probably more...

Answer (score 1):

You can create a PL SQL procedure that returns a ref cursor.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE foo(p_terr_id IN TERRITORY_PROFILE_MSTR.TERRITORY_ID%TYPE, 
  p_recordset out SYS_REFCURSOR) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    OPEN p_recordset FOR
    /* Your SQL here */
END foo;
/
```

More details and examples [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets.php)

Comment: I don't get it. How can I execute this?

Comment: How about what if I don't need a parameter?

Comment: Sir I'm going to use the stored procedure in ReportViewer (SSRS) in ASP.NET. Your solution don't work.

Comment: @ChristianMark If you don't need the parameter, remove it

Comment: @ChristianMark This block creates a function that returns the record set as a ref cursor which, I believe, is what you wanted

Comment: Sir I want it to be compatible to SSRS in ASP.NET wherein if you execute the sp it will return a table or result like you are running a query. Is that possible?

Comment: I have updated my question. I have successfully created what you answered but I want it to be specific to SSRS function (+1 for that)

Comment: According to the following article, ssrs only accepts procedures with out parameters, not function, updating sample code... http://database.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/sql-server-l/getting-data-from-an-oracle-sp-ref-cursor-3304405