# Split string in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, split

I have table with 3 rows in example:

```
|-Id-||--props--|
1        aa = black
2        aa = change
         d = eexplore
3        xxx = yield
         d = int
         mmmm = no
```

I want to write SQL statement with results:

```
aa    
d
xxx
mmm
```

I.e. output all first elements in pairs x=y. The pairs in each row of given table could be separated by `newline`.

I've tried the following SQL but the results are doesn't correct

```
    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('a = b, b = c',
                          '[^=]',
                          1,
                          LEVEL) as name
      FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT REGEXP_COUNT ('a = b, b = c', '=') FROM DUAL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly try the below,the sql fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/39086)

`with names as
(
 SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (regexp_replace('aa = b, bb = c , eee = d','[[:space:]]*',''),
                          '[^=]+',
                          1,
                         level ) as name
      FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT REGEXP_COUNT ('a = b, b = c , e = d ', '=') FROM DUAL))
select nvl(regexp_substr(name,'[^,]+',1,2),regexp_substr(name,'[^,]+',1,1) ) from names;`

**Update1:**-You can replace the new line with comma

On Unix, LINEFEED (chr(10)) is the "end of line" marker. 
On windows  CARRIAGE RETURN/LINEFEED (chr(13)||chr(10)) should be the end of line marker

```
with names as
(
 SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (regexp_replace(replace('aa = black' ||chr(13)||chr(10)||'bb = change'||chr(13)||chr(10)||'mmmm=no',chr(13)||chr(10),','),'[[:space:]]*',''),
                          '[^=]+',
                          1,
                         level ) as name
      FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT REGEXP_COUNT 
('aa = black' ||chr(13)||chr(10)||'bb = change'||chr(13)||chr(10)||'mmmm=no', '=')
 FROM DUAL)

)
select nvl(regexp_substr(name,'[^,]+',1,2),
regexp_substr(name,'[^,]+',1) ) from names;
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is good for comma-separated example. (as in my question SQL ), but I need `newline` separated example.

Comment: The another question that is using your answer is in http://stackoverflow.com/q/27602170/2023524.

Comment: may be this might help your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25524281/oracle-how-to-create-a-function-returning-values-for-a-select-from-tab-where/25528438#25528438

Answer (score 0):

Use [substr](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/substr.php) to return the first character:

```
select substr(LEVEL, 1, 1) from tablename group by substr(LEVEL, 1, 1)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. But the name of first word can contain more than 1 character. I've updated my question.