# Union results from subselect

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have an SQL statement with following structure:

```
f(string parameter)=select * from table(parameter) ...
=> results in some table with rows.
```

f(string parameter) is used as shortcut for more complex sql subquery.

```
table parameters:

|---params----|
   param1
   param2
   param3
   ....
```

how to combine `f()` with the table `parameters` where f() will be called for each param in this table. My question refers to SQL statement itself. As result I expect

```
f(param1)
  union all
f(param2)
  union all
f(param3)
...
```

If someone is interested what is staying in f() refer to my previous question answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27599637/2023524.

Comment: Can't you just include those parameter as `OR` condition? You can probably as well use CTE.

Comment: The number of elements in table `parameters` is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

You can define f as a function like the below

```
create or replace function f(param IN VARCHAR2) return varchar2 is
  Result varchar2(32767);
begin
  with names as(
    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(regexp_replace(replace(param,
                                                chr(13) || chr(10),
                                                ','),
                                        '[[:space:]]*',
                                        ''),
                         '[^=]+',
                         1,
                         level) as name
      FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT REGEXP_COUNT(param, '=') FROM DUAL)

     )

      select LISTAGG(nvl(regexp_substr(name, '[^,]+', 1, 2),
                         regexp_substr(name, '[^,]+', 1)),
                     ',') WITHIN
       GROUP(
       ORDER BY name)
        INTO Result
        from names;

  return(Result);
end f;
```

Then you can call your parameters like the below

```
with parameter(param) as (
    select 'aa = black' ||chr(13)||chr(10)||'bb = change'||chr(13)||chr(10)||'mmmm=no'  
    from dual union  all
   select 'aa = black' ||chr(13)||chr(10)||'bb = change'||chr(13)||chr(10)||'kkk=no' from dual
    )
    select distinct regexp_substr(f(param),'[^,]+',1,level) from parameter
    connect by level <=regexp_count(f(param),',')+1;
```

**Update1:**-Just for your information You can call a function within an Anonymous Block like the below

```
DECLARE
  function f(param IN VARCHAR2) return varchar2 is
    Result varchar2(32767);
  begin
    with names as(
      SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(regexp_replace(replace(param,
                                                  chr(13) || chr(10),
                                                  ','),
                                          '[[:space:]]*',
                                          ''),
                           '[^=]+',
                           1,
                           level) as name
        FROM DUAL
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT REGEXP_COUNT(param, '=') FROM DUAL)

       )

        select LISTAGG(nvl(regexp_substr(name, '[^,]+', 1, 2),
                           regexp_substr(name, '[^,]+', 1)),
                       ',') WITHIN
         GROUP(
         ORDER BY name)
          INTO Result
          from names;


    return(Result);
  end f;
begin
  for i in 1 .. (regexp_count(f('aa = black' || chr(13) || chr(10) ||
                                'bb = change' || chr(13) || chr(10) ||
                                'kkk=no'),
                              ',') + 1) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(regexp_substr(f('aa = black' || chr(13) ||
                                         chr(10) || 'bb = change' ||
                                         chr(13) || chr(10) || 'kkk=no'),
                                       '[^,]+',
                                       1,
                                       i));
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: unfortunately I could not test your function because I don't permit to create new functions in my db.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 11g, I think you can just do this in the `from` clause:

```
with params as (
      select param1 as param from dual union all
      select param2 union all
      select param3
     )
select *
from params p,
     table(f(p.param)) f;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately I get `ORA-00904 invalid identifier` if I change parameter to p.param. As `f` is only a shortcut to some sql statement and will be expanded in from clause.

Comment: @Tony . . . I don't understand.  Is your question about a subquery or about a table function?

Comment: The question was about subquery. I've used this ambiguous notation to simplify the explanation. But I'm thankful for every information I get. I've learnt very much about sql and databases from your answers.