# Sum comma separated values in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I need Oracle SQL function which sums comma separated values.

For example, this function needs to return 100 from string:

```
0,4,2,88,6
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split function in oracle to comma separated values with automatic sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28677070/split-function-in-oracle-to-comma-separated-values-with-automatic-sequence)

Comment: @sagi - not completely as the OP wants to return the sum of the split values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a solution without regular expressions:

```
create or replace function calc(i_str in varchar2)
  return number is l_result number;
begin
  execute immediate 'select ' || i_str || ' from dual'
    into l_result;
  return l_result;
exception
  when others then
    return null;
end;

select calc(replace('0,4,2,88,6', ',', '+')) from dual
--> 100
```

Comment: Yes, you've done it with out regular expressions but you have opened up all sorts of security holes with SQL injection. I would never let this code be used on a production system. `SELECT CALC( '(SELECT user_password_hash FROM users_data WHERE id = 1 )' ) FROM DUAL`

Comment: You are right. This function should never be called directly in production system from outside. But in some cases this could be a solution, e. g. Preparation of data for inital data load.

Answer (score 4):

```
select sum(regexp_substr('0,4,2,88,6', '[^,]+', 1, level)) as result
from dual
connect by regexp_substr('0,4,2,88,6', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null;
```

Answer (score 3):

A pure PL/SQL solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sum_split_String(
  i_str    IN  VARCHAR2,
  i_delim  IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC
AS
  p_sum          NUMBER := 0;
  p_start        NUMBER(5) := 1;
  p_end          NUMBER(5);
  c_len CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_str );
  c_ld  CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_delim );
BEGIN
  IF i_str IS NULL THEN
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;
  p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
  WHILE p_end > 0 LOOP
    p_sum := p_sum + TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, p_end - p_start ) );
    p_start := p_end + c_ld;
    p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
  END LOOP;
  IF p_start <= c_len + 1 THEN
    p_sum := p_sum + TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, c_len - p_start + 1 ) );
  END IF;
  RETURN p_sum;
END;
/
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT SUM_SPLIT_STRING( '0,4,2,88,6' ) AS sum FROM DUAL;
```

**Output**:

```
SUM
---
100
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no Oracle function that does this out of the box. 
In SQL, you can maybe use a pivot table to split the string into numbers

```
with MyString  as
 (select '0,4,2,88,6' Str from dual
  )
,pivot as (
  Select Rownum Pnum
  From dual
  Connect By Rownum <= 100   
  )
SELECT sum(to_number(REGEXP_SUBSTR (ms.Str,'[^,]+',1,pv.pnum))) Num
  FROM MyString ms
      ,pivot pv
where REGEXP_SUBSTR (ms.Str,'[^,]+',1,pv.pnum) is not null
```