# Split multiple values in a cell to multiple rows - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, split

I have a table:

table1

```
values
------------
x=new letter
------------
a=old letter
ba=older letter
xq=newer letter
------------
xf=new apple
xt=new orange
x3=new fruit
xtt=new seed
```

I have to separate the values in each cell to multiple rows.

The following is the output:

table2

```
code      description
x         new letter
a         old letter
ba        older letter
xq        newer letter
xf        new apple
xt        new orange
x3        new fruit
xtt       new seed
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: look at this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28677070/split-function-in-oracle-to-comma-separated-values-with-automatic-sequence

Comment: Hint: use `regexp_substr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `regexp_replace()` or `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr(str, '^[^=]+') as code,
       regexp_substr(str, '[^=]+$') as value
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ed4caf426b56788817decc617deccb7f) is a db<>fiddle.

Note that this does not use `values` for the column name.  That is a very bad choice for a column name because it is a SQL keyword.

Comment: Would it also separate multiple values in a single cell to multiple rows?

Comment: The second row has multi line value present. a=old letter
ba=older letter
xq=newer letter are in 1 cell with new line

Answer (score 2):

try like below

```
SELECT NVL(SUBSTR('a=old letter', 0, INSTR('a=old letter', '=')-1), 'a=old letter') 
AS col1, NVL(SUBSTR('a=old letter', INSTR('a=old letter', '=')+1), 'a=old letter')    
  FROM DUAL
```

so in you case

```
SELECT NVL(SUBSTR(values, 0, INSTR(values, '=')-1), values) 
AS col1, NVL(SUBSTR(values, INSTR(values, '=')+1), values) 

  FROM table1
```

Comment: the second cell contains multi line values - a=old letter
ba=older letter
xq=newer letter, the sql above does not break multi line value to separate rows.