# How can I break an string in different pieces, and shift each piece split one level down?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Using SQL ORACLE:

I need to break a series of strings into separate pieces and each subsequent piece needs to fall below the one before it, i.e. Listed vertically, one piece per row. I want to separate the strings at the '^' symbol.

For example, The string is 'RT12^RT45^LT44^TR55'

The result needs to be:

```
RT12
RT45
LT44
TR55
```

Comment: I'm not sure what "shift one level down" means if you want the result to have a single row.  Do you just want to replace the carat character `^` with a carriage return (CR) or carriage return and line feed (CR LF) (Windows and Unix have a different line terminator)?

Comment: Also, why is the last line `TR^55`?  Why wouldn't you split that on the caret?

Comment: use replace or translate function to replace ^ to a cr lf character，or do it with java code ,it is more flexible

Comment: Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28677070/split-function-in-oracle-to-comma-separated-values-with-automatic-sequence)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 SELECT
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(TRIM('^' FROM 'RT12^RT45^LT44^TR55'), '[^\^]+', 1, LEVEL) AS res
   FROM
      DUAL
  CONNECT BY
     LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(TRIM('^' FROM 'RT12^RT45^LT44^TR55'), '\^')+1
```

Comment: combine your answers into one (or even better to delete the other, this is already pretty nice)