# How to merge two tables in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

I have one EMPLOYEE table which is having employee Id and employee name mapping

[image]

another table is TEAM_EMP_MAP which is having team and employee mapping

[image]

so as per TEAM_EMP_MAP table a team with team id 1111 is having these employee EMP_1, EMP_2 and EMP_4.
I need output like below with help of TEAM_EMP_MAP and EMPLOYEE table.

[image]

I have checked lot on google but not got success.

Comment: is this mysql or oracle?

Comment: it is for oracle database

Comment: Storing comma separated values in a single column is a really bad idea. Do you have a chance to fix that broken database design?

Comment: I would echo previous comment, in that your design of TEAM_EMP_APP is seriously and  fatally flawed.  You need to study up on "data normalization". Those comma seperated values should each be their own row.  Yes, that means you will be repeating ORG_ID values, but that, in itself, is not a concern.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - i am agree with you, i will fix this broken database designs. thanks for valuable reply.

Comment: Good to hear :) Separating multi-valued fields into separate rows, with all the flexibility and validation that makes possible, is pretty much the reason for relational databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use the operator `LIKE` in the `ON` clause of the join of the tables like this:

```
SELECT t.ORG_ID TEAM_ID, 
       e.EMP_NM EMPLOYEE_NAME 
FROM TEAM_EMP_MAP t INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE e
ON ',' || t.EMPLOYEES || ',' LIKE '%,' || e.EMP_ID || ',%'
```

See he [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8b51bb1e29b95f498b459d0126ee0a48).
Results:

```
> TEAM_ID | EMPLOYEE_NAME
> :------ | :------------
> 1111    | EMP_1        
> 1111    | EMP_3        
> 1111    | EMP_4
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i understand, you need to fix your TEAM_EMP_MAP table with correct many to many associations.

I think you can use Regex (REGEXP_SUBSTR) i this case to split your comma separed columns.
Have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28677070/split-function-in-oracle-to-comma-separated-values-with-automatic-sequence) to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use REGEXP_SUBSTR and CONNECT LEVEL BY to split the content in the array of the second table.

Let me show you an example:

```
SQL> create table y ( id_emp number , name varchar2(2) ) ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into y values ( 101 , 'A' ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> insert into y values ( 104, 'B' ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> insert into y values ( 103 , 'C' ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> commit ;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from t ;

        ID VAL
---------- -------------
      1111 101,104,103

SQL> select * from y ;

    ID_EMP NAME
---------- ----
       101 A
       104 B
       103 C

SQL> with emps as ( SELECT regexp_substr(val, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) as empid FROM t
  2  CONNECT BY regexp_substr(val, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL )
  3  select y.name , emps.empid from y inner join emps on ( y.id_emp = emps.empid ) ;

NAME EMPID
---- -----------------------------
A    101
B    104
C    103
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with t as (
select org_id
      ,employees txt
  from team_emp_map
 where org_id = 1111
)
,emp as ( -- split string into records
select org_id
      ,regexp_substr(t.txt, '\d+', 1, level) emp_id
  from t
connect by regexp_substr(t.txt, '\d+', 1, level) is not null
)
select emp.org_id
      ,employee.emp_nm
  from emp
      ,employee
 where emp.emp_id = employee.emp_id
```